# Can you set more than one property when pushing a Pagestack?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml

I am writing an app for uTouch and I want to deliver more than one property.

The code for one property:

```
pageStack.push(folgen,{serie: "himym"})
```

Is it possible to deliver more than one property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pass multiple properties. Just use:

```
pageStack.push(pageId, {prop1: "value1", prop2: "value2"})
```

Here's a working example:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

MainView {
    id: root
    width: units.gu(50)
    height: units.gu(50)

    PageStack {
        id: pageStack

        Component.onCompleted: {
            push(home, {labelText: "You can pass multiple properties.",
                        title: "Example",
                        fSize: "large"})
        }

        Page {
            id: home
            property var labelText: ""
            property var fSize: ""

            Label {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: home.labelText
                fontSize: home.fSize
            }
        }
    }
}
```